# mode_rewrite will not enable apache2

Tags: apache-2.4

On Ubuntu 16.04, trying to get mod_rewrite to work locally.

Apache2 (2.4.18) is installed, I can serve pages
"sudo a2enmod rewrite outputs" "Module rewrite already enabled".  Verified by checking mods_enabled and that the lib file actually exists.
Restarted apache
When I run phpinfo() on a page, mod_rewrite is non-existent.

Comment: You can use `apachectl -M` to verify explicitly if a module is loaded. This is a slightly more *standard* way than calling the httpd binary directly as in the response below.

Answer (score 0):

phpinfo() may not be the correct way to check for an Apache module, you can use PHP as an Apache module or managed with php-fpm.

To check for mod_rewrite as it directly to Apache, not sure about Ubuntu but on RedHat 6 and older you can use:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -M -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep mod_rewrite
```

Change the paths according to your install. Example output:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -M -f /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep rewrite
Syntax OK
 rewrite_module (shared)
#
```